# Zipping arrays with every n-th element

Tags: ruby, arrays

Is there a way to use `zip` in such a way that 2 arrays will be zipped with spaces between n-elements such as:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = ["x","y","z"]
n = 3
```

the result will be

```
res = [[1,"x"],2,3,[4,"y"],5,6,[7,"z"],8,9,10] # note that 10 is alone and b is not cycled
```

Comment: You may learn a lot of things from Haskell, one of them is to use plural names for collections (`as`, `bs`) and keep singular ones (`a`, `b`) for its elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd write:

```
res = a.each_slice(n).zip(b).flat_map do |xs, y| 
  y ? [[xs.first, y], *xs.drop(1)] : xs
end
#=> [[1, "x"], 2, 3, [4, "y"], 5, 6, [7, "z"], 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
a.map.with_index{|x, i| i%n < 1 && b.size > i/n ? [x, b[i/n]] : x}
#=> [[1, "x"], 2, 3, [4, "y"], 5, 6, [7, "z"], 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Are you sure? This results in `[[10, "x"]]` here.

Comment: Maybe you have an extra x in your b?

Comment: I apologize for waisting your time - can't reproduce the output.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over b is  a possibility:

```
# Note this destroys array a;use a dup it if it is needed elsewhere
res = b.flat_map{|el| [[el].unshift(a.shift), *a.shift(n-1)] }.concat(a)
```